# I can't understand the increment portions of for loops in c language for specific problem

Tags: c, for-loop, increment, conio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    for(ch=getche(); ch!='q'; ch=getche());
    printf("Found the q");
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand how the for loop here works . I can understand the initialization and the conditional test . But don't get why I have to use getche function again in increment portions .

Comment: How else would ch change?

Comment: Just as a side note: If you change the `for` loop to a `do`...`while` loop, you only have to write `getche` once instead of twice: `do { ch=getche(); } while ( ch!='q' );`

Answer (score 4):

It may help to rewrite this `for` loop into an equivalent `while` loop:

```
for(ch=getche(); ch!='q'; ch=getche());
```

becomes

```
ch = getche();
while (ch != 'q') {
    ch = getche();
}
```

So you repeatedly get a new character by calling `getche`, until  the character you get is equal to `'q'`.

Without the second `ch=getche()`, you would get only a single character and compare this to `'q'` over and over again (leading to an infinite loop if it isn't `'q'`).

Answer (score 1):

Remember how a `for` loop typically works:

```
for ( init-expressionopt ; test-expressionopt ; update-expressionopt )
  statement
```

*`init-expression`* (if present) is evaluated exactly once; it (typically) sets up the thing we’re testing against. In this case, it initializes the value the of `ch` by calling `getche`.

Before each loop iteration, *`test-expression`* (if present) is evaluated; if zero, the loop exits.  In this case, the test is `ch != 'q'`.

*After* each loop iteration, *`update-expression`* (if present) is evaluated; it updates the thing we’re testing against. In this case, it updates the value of `ch` by executing another `getche` call.  Without this step, the value of `ch` would not change and the loop would execute indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear rewrite the for loop:

```
for(ch=getche(); ch!='q'; ch=getche());
```

the following way:

```
for(ch=getche(); ch!='q'; )
{
    ch=getche();
}
```

That is the statement in the body of the second for loop:

```
ch=getche();
```

is moved as an expression in the third part of the first for loop.

In the third part of for loop there may be used any expression not only an expression with the increment or decrement operator.